# How to pass values through helm --set

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a values.yaml file:

```yaml
secret:
   - name: secret__1
     value: secret1
   - name: secret__2
     value: secret2
   - name: secret__3
     value: secret3
   - name: secret__4
     value:  secret4
```

There are more than 20 name,value pairs.
How to use helm set command for this?

Comment: You can use `--set-file` option to provide values from a file.

Comment: But I have a deployment yaml file where values need to be set from name and value.
`code`
env:
          {{ range $key, $value := .Values.secret }}
            - name: {{ $key }}
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ $value }}
                  key: {{ $value }}
          {{end}}

Answer (score 2):

Technically it's possible to specify each of these individual values using `helm install --set` but that would become a very long command line and you'd be very dependent on the actual order of the options in the chart's `values.yaml` file.  Also see [The Format and Limitations of `--set`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of---set) in the Helm documentation.

```bash
helm install some-release . \
  --set 'secret[0].value=password1' \
  --set 'secret[1].value=credential2' \
  ...
  --set 'secret[19].value=secret20'
```

You could `--set` a value to an array of strings, or `--set` an individual field in an object using array-index syntax, but you cannot `--set` a value to a complex object or `--set` an array of objects.

A much simpler approach is to put these values in a separate YAML file and provide them using an addition `helm install -f` option.

```yaml
# local-secrets.yaml
secret:
   - name: secret__1
     value: password1
   - name: secret__2
     value: credential2
   ...
   - name: secret__20
     value:  secret20
```

```bash
helm install some-release . -f local-secrets.yaml
```

This value overrides the `secrets:` in your chart's `values.yaml` file; its value is visible using the normal Helm `.Values` syntax.  The file does not need to specifically be checked into source control, if for example your CD system might generate it at deploy time.